# Trying to turn Simple_form gem's collection radio's wrapper into <li> element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I am using the simple_form gem (https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) to help out the forms in my app. But I'd like to display the many radio buttons I've got here in li tag. Simple_form now generates span wrapper tag for each radio buttons. Like this:

```
 <%= t.input :arrives_in, :collection => [1,2,3,4], :as => :radio %>
 #=> <span><input type='radio'><label>1</label></span>
```

any way I can have it wrap the input and label part in an li instead of span?

Thank YOU!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass `:item_wrapper_tag` to you input like this:

```
<%= t.input :arrives_in, :collection => [1,2,3,4], :as => :radio,
                         :item_wrapper_tag => :li %>
```

You can also, pass the `:collection_wrapper_tag` option to change the wrapper of all radio inputs like this:

```
<%= t.input :arrives_in, :collection => [1,2,3,4], :as => :radio,
                         :item_wrapper_tag => :li,
                         :collection_wrapper_tag => :ul %>
```

Comment: Thanks Rafael! Where did you find this information? On Simple_form's github main page?

Comment: No, I see the source code. Also I'm one of maintainers of the project. We are improving the documentation, so you will be able to find things like this easily.

Comment: wow, what a pleasure! can't thank you enough to personally answer my question. -- I proceeded to google for the term "item_wrapper_tag" and "collection_wrapper_tag" to find some source code pages wherein I also see a whole bunch other options/settings. I will from now sort of follow the "item_wrapper_tag api" search result. Thank you for this gem (for some reason, I had thought Jose Valim was the author, perhaps you took it over?) Anyways, it's much lighter and hence less intimidating than some other form  helpers ;)

Comment: Actually the authors are Carlos Antonio da Silva and José Valim. I work with them at PlataformaTec and I'm one of SimpleForm's maintainers now.

Comment: ahh, I see. In fact, just got some help from Carlos on Google Groups. Cheers!

Comment: Worth noting that the option `:item_wrapper_tag` did not work for me by default. When using the default `boolean_style = :nested`, this overrides the `:item_wrapper_tag` to always be a `:label:`.

Answer (score 0):

Tried the accepted answer.  It stuck bullets in front of my radio buttons fine, but it still didn't display inline.  I just did it with CSS. I slapped a div with class="radio-buttons" around the buttons and label. Then I added this to my style sheet (SASS):

```
.radio-buttons {
  margin: .5em 0;
  span input {
    float: left;
    margin-right: .25em;
    margin-top: -.25em;
  }
  #this grabs the MAIN label only for my radio buttons 
  #since the data type for the table column is string--yours may be different
  label.string { 
    margin-bottom: .5em !important;
  }

  clear: both;
}

.form-block {
  clear: both;
  margin-top: .5em;
}

 .radio-buttons span {
  clear: both;
  display:block;
 }
```

This will make the radio buttons inline on ALL frameworks, though this is tweaked to look the best for Zurb Foundation. ;)